# GridControl Aboult

Tags: linq, gridcontrol

My aim is to give a warning by coloring the column in the warning section in the giridcontrol section, if the date entered in the warning part, colOfferDate, has passed 7 days from today's date.

```
void Listele()
{
    var lst = (from s in context.TeklifFormları
               select new
               {

                   s.ProjeKodu,
                   s.MusteriIletisimTarih,
                   s.TeklifTarih,
                   s.FirmaIsmi,
                   s.Makina,
                   s.Ebat,
                   s.MusteriTipi,
                   s.TeklifSonucu,
                   s.ReferansAdSoyad,
                   s.MusteriTanısmaYeri,
                   s.SozlesmeTarih,
                   s.SiparisTarih,
                   s.Hafta,
                   s.Ülke,
                   s.Fiyat,
                   s.TeklifKodu,
                   s.BirinciAciklama,
                   s.IkinciAciklama,
                   s.Yıl,
                   Uyarı= DateTime.Now-colTeklifTarih
               }).ToList();
            gridcontMusteri.DataSource = lst;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. The question is really vague. Please take a moment and read [ask] and edit your question with [mcve] of your code and explain in detail what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: My problem is the question. If it's 7 days after offer classes, gridcontrol also asked me to alert